# javascript method to check a valid URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url, uri

I  there any **JavaScript** way **(regex) or module** to check if a string is a URL which the follows following schema http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme.

**NOTE -**
I have seen other questions related to this in stackoverflow and none of them are satisfactory.
Most of them are the regex which matches the **http/https/ftp** URL but what about **feed or mailto** URL or URL with any other schema as specified in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

The following regex does what you are requesting.

It validates a string if it holds a URL as specified in RFC 3986.

Both absolute and relative URLs are supported.

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:(//([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=]+@)?([a-z0-9\-._~%]+|\[[a-f0-9:.]+\]|\[v[a-f0-9][a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\])(:[0-9]+)?(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?|(/?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?)?)| ([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?|(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+/?))(\?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?(\#[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?$
```

> I did not come up with this regex, it is created by JGSoft

Comment: can you please write the function isURl() . I used your regex in my javaScript code, and getting error.